# How to make register using email/password and send Code to the phone in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to allow users to register an account on my app using flutter with email/password, and then send code to the phone. So when user enters their data to Sign up, it should register them with their email and then use their phone to the verity code. Also the user can't complete the registration and go to the Home page Without checking the entered code.

But in my code it's not working what i want do it.

My click function:

```
dynamic ruselt= await _auth.regsiterwithemail(_emailcontroller.text,_passwordcontroller.text);
if (ruselt!=null){
setState(() async {
  loading =false;
verfitycode().verfityphoen(context);
});
}else{
  setState(() {
    loading=false;

    SweetAlert.show(context,
        title: "Title",
        style: SweetAlertStyle.confirm,
        subtitle: "Subtitle");
  });
}
```

My registration function:

```
Future  regsiterwithemail(String email , String password )
async {
  try{
    AuthResult result =await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user =result.user;

    print('oky');
    return _userfirebaseUser(user);

  }catch(e){

print(e.toString());
return null;
  }
}
```

**class for verity code**

```
class verfitycode {

  String phonenumber;
  String smsCode;
  String vialdid;

  GlobalKey<FormState>_form;

  Future<void> verfityphoen(BuildContext context)async{

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout AutoRetriv =(String verid) {
      this.vialdid =verid;
    };


    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeset =(String verid,[int forceResendingToken]){
      this.vialdid=verid;
      smscodeDialog(context);

    };
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verfiedcompletd=(AuthCredential user){
      print('verfild');
    };
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verfilederror =(AuthException exception){
      print('${exception.message}');
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber:"+967776523152",
        timeout: const Duration(seconds:5),
        verificationCompleted: verfiedcompletd,
        verificationFailed: verfilederror,
        codeSent: smsCodeset,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: AutoRetriv
    );
  }

  Future<bool> smscodeDialog(BuildContext context){
    Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "رمز التحقق",
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: _form,
              child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child:
            TextField(
              onChanged: (val){
                this.smsCode=val;
              },
              decoration:InputDecoration (
                icon: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
                labelText: 'ادخل رمز التحقق',
              ),
            ),
    )
            )
          ],

        ),
        buttons: [

          DialogButton(
              child: Text('خروج', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize:18)), onPressed:()=>Navigator.pop(context)),
          DialogButton(
            onPressed:  (){
                //  _form.currentState.validate();
                FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
                  } else {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    _testSignlink();
                  }
                });

    },
            child: Text(
              "ادخل الرمز",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize:18),
            ),
          ),
        ]).show();

  }
  _testSignlink() async {
    FirebaseUser user;
    String _smsCodeController;
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: vialdid,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    await user.linkWithCredential(credential).then((user){
      print(user.user.uid);
    }).catchError((onError){
      print(onError.toString());
    });
    _smsCodeController = '';
    return 'signInWithPhoneNumber succeeded: $user';
  }
}
```

Comment: "But in my code it's not working what i want do it." There's quite some code here, and it's a complex registration process. Which specific line of code isn't doing what you want it to do?

Comment: I have form reqired included TextFormField email and password and phone Now I want register by email / password but the verify code sent to the phone To confirm the account and complete the registration

Comment: That's a great use-case, but not a question. Where on implementing this use-case are you stuck, and how does it relate to the code you shared?

Comment: Do you mean that it is difficult to implement my idea